# "Compound selectors may no longer be extended" error being thrown when running "ng serve."

Tags: angular, sass, node-sass, libsass

While trying to `ng serve` I keep getting the same error message.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

                @extend i.skinny_arrow;
                       ^
      Compound selectors may no longer be extended.
Consider "@extend i, .skinny_arrow" instead.
See https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#disallowed-selectors for details.
```

I have tried using `npm rebuild node-sass` because it seems to be a sass issue of some kind but rebuilding it did nothing. Things to note are that three people (one who is running linux and two who are running macOS) are able to run the same code without any issue. However, I'm running windows and it refuses to work. Also I'm running node-sass version 4.13.1 and libsass version 3.5.4.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Nope. I've had to just rip out all things that used @extend and tried to find another solution. That seems to be the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The way of handling this has changed. So, Instead of

```
@extend i.skinny_arrow;
```

You do

```
@extend i, .skinny_arrow
```

That should work.

Comment: `@extend i.skinny_arrow` is not the same as `@extend i, .skinny_arrow`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help someone from [original docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/extend-compound)

> Because Sass doesn’t know the details of the HTML the CSS is going to
> style, any @extend might need to generate extra selectors that won’t
> apply to your HTML in particular. This is especially true when
> switching away from extending compound selectors.
>
> Most of the time, these extra selectors won’t cause any problems, and
> will only add a couple of extra bytes to gzipped CSS. But some
> stylesheets might be relying more heavily on the old behavior. In that
> case, we recommend replacing the compound selector with a placeholder
> selector.

```
// Instead of just `.message.info`.
%message-info, .message.info {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.heads-up {
  // Instead of `.message.info`.
  @extend %message-info;
}
```

Do check the link above